# How to use Plivo call API

Tags: php, pdo, freeswitch, plivo

I am using plivo and have calls answered by `welcome.php` as my `welcome url`.

When a call is answered, I pass it to `conf_handler.php` and enter it into a conference:

```
    $conf_attr = array(
        'callbackUrl' => $host.'conf_handler.php',
        'callbackMethod' => "POST",
        );

    $r->addConference($conf_name,$conf_attr);

    echo($r->toXML());
```

How can I store both the `callUUID` and `call_duration` (once hang up) as a variables within `conf_handler.php`? Are they posted to the page with the callbackMethod? Or do I need to somehow use GET to look them up (how would I do this?) http://plivo.com/docs/api/call/#call_detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do both ways.

1) **From `hangup_url`** (within your `welcome.php`). When a call is answered, Plivo sends a POST request with a set of parameters including the two. So you can parse the request from there. (Check out the "Request Parameters" section at http://plivo.com/docs/xml/request/)

2) **From `callbackUrl`** (within your `conf_handler.php'). Once you set up the`conf_handler.php`in the`callbackUrl`, Plivo will send a set of parameters as described at  http://plivo.com/docs/xml/dial/#dialcallbackUrl

After that, you just need to parse the POST request and store as variables. (perhaps you could refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

Let me know if anything isn't clear. And I work at Plivo.